# extent report 2.41 throws null pointer when logger is in method ( class 1) called from method (class 2)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at runnerClasses.Class1.meth1(Class1.java:106)
    at runnerClasses.Class2.meth2(Class2.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Here is the code

```
public class Class1Method1{
    public ExtentReports report;
    ExtentTest logger;

    @BeforeClass
    public void somemeth(){

        report = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\Reports\\TestReport.html", false, DisplayOrder.NEWEST_FIRST);
        report.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\Reports\\extent-config.xml"));
        logger = report.startTest("desc", "Test1");
    }

    @Test()
    public void meth1(String some1){

    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "desc");

    }

    @AfterClass
     public void afterreports(){
         report.flush();
         driver.quit();
     }
   }     


    Class2Method2{

    public ExtentReports report;
    ExtentTest logger;

    @BeforeClass
    public void somemeth1(){

    report = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\Reports\\TestReport.html", false, DisplayOrder.NEWEST_FIRST);

    report.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\Reports\\extent-config.xml"));

    logger = report.startTest("desc", "Test1");

    }

    @Test()
    public void meth2() throws InterruptedException {
            class1.meth1("Para1")
        } 

    @AfterClass

    public void afterreports(){
         report.flush();
        driver.quit();
     }
    }
```

extent report 2.41 throws null pointer when logger is in method ( class 1) called from method (class 2)
extent logger is in method of class1 which is being called in method of class2.
if I comment the extent report logger in Class1Method1, code works well..am i missing something???

unable to edit here anymore...

Comment: attach your full code. at least the declaration parts to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Have added the extent report declarations... all other declarations are in string or converted to string from integer...sorry .. wont be able to reveal much due to sec issue as working in a fin company... As I said earlier..it looks like error is coz of logger line that is what trace points to... do you think its coz of the parameter or arguments that are passed? for more info am using DataProvider with testng

Comment: are you generating extent reports for each class? is that your actual requirement?

Comment: @Ricky Please clarify the question details.

Comment: Yes ..generating it for each class ...I am using testng.xml ..so initiating it in @BeforeClass....so on the left of the report are all the classes and when clicked on it ..gives you the logged steps for each method on the right of the report

Comment: @Ricky Have you flush the Report in each class? Stil your question details are not clear. Please format the code.

Comment: have pushed more edit to clean up the code a bit.... appreciate your help and thanks for yoru patience...question is why I am getting null pointer when I execute class2???? ...on debugging it points to extent logger line of method in class1....when i comment the logger of method in class1 ... code works perfectly fine

Comment: not sure if changing the report version from 2.41 to 3.x would help but would try tomorrow to see if it works

Comment: I don't under Without logger what can you achieve so far !

Comment: @Ricky Try http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#basic-example

Comment: @Ishita Shah:: what do you mean "I don't under Without logger what can you achieve so far !" so i have implemented the basic example in meth1 and called it in meth2 and its failing there